# Telit UL865 3G Modem ATD*99***1# Command “NO CARRIER” Response

Tags: embedded, gsm, tcp, m2m, ppp

Currently, I am working on Telit UL865-EUD 3G Modem. I worked with Telit GL865 GPRS modem before that's why I am familiar with AT commands and initialization logic.

My problem is that my UL865 modem always returns "NO CARRIER" to ATD*99***1# command. It is not only specific to ATD*99***1#. It results also same with other ATD Commands.

UL865 module is working. I attached to the network and open TCP socket. I tested them. But Dial Commands are not working.

My AT Command Log output is in below

Firmware Version : 12.00.616

```
AT 
OK

AT&K=0
OK

AT#SCFG=3,1,300,600,300,10
OK

AT#SLED=2,2,2
OK

AT#SLEDSAV
OK

AT#FRWL=1,"1.2.3.4","0.0.0.0"
OK

AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","mgbs"
OK

AT+CGSN
355855052854914
OK

AT#ICMP=2
OK

AT+CSQ
+CSQ: 24,2
OK

AT+CCLK?
+CCLK: "17/10/05,18:55:06+12"
OK

AT#SGACT=1,1,"mgbs",""
#SGACT: 5.***.***.***
OK

AT+COPS?
+COPS: 0,0,"TURKCELL",2
OK

AT+CREG?
+CREG: 0,1
OK

AT#USERID=""
OK

AT#PASSW=""
OK

AT#GAUTH=0
OK

AT#GPPPCFG="000.000.000.000"
OK

ATD*99***1#
NO CARRIER
```

Is there anybody who faces the same problem before?

Comment: is that data SIM ?

Comment: Yes It is Data SIM

Comment: Check whether call facility is available for that SIM

Comment: It is active. Same SIM Card is working with same commands in GL865 GPRS Module.

Answer (score 0):

Before the ATD command, try send:

```
AT+CUSD=1
```

This command in the Telit 3G Modules AT Commands Reference Guide:

> allows control of the Unstructured Supplementary Service Data

Note that you are sending an USSD command (e.g. ATD*100#).